# Malloc function in dynamic lists

Tags: c, list, dynamic

I'm getting started with dynamic lists and i don't understand why it is necessary to use the malloc function even when declaring the first node in the main() program, the piece of code below should just print the data contained in the first node but if i don't initialize the node with the malloc function it just doesn't work:

```
 struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void insert(int val, struct node*);

int main() {
    struct node* head ;
    head->data = 2;
    printf("%d \n", head->data);

}
```

Comment: `struct node* head;` is just a pointer to a `struct node`, which doesn't exist yet. You use `malloc` to allocate memory,, in this case for a `struct node`. Your `head->` invokes undefined behavior since `head` doesn't yet point to valid memory. You say it should just print the data in the first node .. you have zero nodes. You must allocate some memory for a node first to create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t technically, but maintaining all nodes with the same memory pattern is only an advantage to you, with no real disadvantages.

Just assume that *all* nodes are stored in the dynamic memory.

Your “insert” procedure would be better named something like “add” or (for full functional context) “cons”, and it should return the new node:

```
struct node* cons(int val, struct node* next)
{
  struct node* this = (struct node*)malloc( sizeof struct node );
  if (!this) return next;  // or some other error condition!
  this->data = val;
  this->next = next;
  return this;
}
```

Building lists is now very easy:

```
int main()
{
  struct node* xs = cons( 2, cons( 3, cons( 5, cons( 7, NULL ) ) ) );
  // You now have a list of the first four prime numbers.
```

And it is easy to handle them.

```
  // Let’s print them!
  {
    struct node* p = xs;
    while (p)
    {
      printf( "%d ", p->data );
      p = p->next;
    }
    printf( "\n" );
  }

  // Let’s get the length!
  int length = 0;
  {
    struct node* p = xs;
    while (p)
    {
      length += 1;
      p = p->next;
    }
  }
  printf( "xs is %d elements long.\n", length );
```

By the way, you should try to be as consistent as possible when naming things. You have named the node data “data” but the constructor’s argument calls it “val”. You should pick one and stick to it.

Also, it is common to:

```
typedef struct node node;
```

Now in every place except inside the definition of `struct node` you can just use the word `node`.

Oh, and I almost forgot: Don’t forget to clean up with a proper destructor.

```
node* destroy( node* root )
{
  if (!root) return NULL;
  destroy( root->next );
  free( root );
  return NULL;
}
```

And an addendum to `main()`:

```
int main()
{
  node* xs = ...

  ...

  xs = destroy( xs );
}
```

Comment: It would be better to have `destroy()` return nothing than just a null pointer.

Comment: No, I disagree. It is better to return a value to assign to the caller’s head pointer, as in the example. But “better” in this case is opinion either way.

Comment: OK. I see why you’re doing it. If I wanted to be sure the pointer in the calling code was null, I’d use a pointer to pointer argument. But it’s not worth fighting over. What you have is OK.

Comment: I’ve done it both ways. I have come to think this way is cleaner (at least, that’s my current opinion, LOL), but either way is just as good.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a variable, you define the type of the variable, then it's
name and optionally you declare it's initial value.

Every type needs an specific amount of memory. For example `int` would be
32 bit long on a 32bit OS, 8 bit long on a 64.

A variable declared in a function is usually stored in the stack associated
with the function. When the function returns, the stack for that function is
no longer available and the variable does not longer exist.

When you need the value/object of the variable to exist even after a function
returns, then you need to allocate memory on a different part of the program,
usually the heap. That's exactly what `malloc`, `realloc` and `calloc` do.

Doing

```
struct node* head ;
head->data = 2;
```

is just wrong. You've declaring a pointer named `head` of type `struct node`,
but you are not assigning anything to it. So it points to an unspecified
location in memory. `head->data = 2` tries to store a value at an unspecified
location and the program will most likely crash with a segfault.

In main you could do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node head;
    head.data = 2;
    printf("%d \n", head.data);
    return 0;
}
```

`head` will be saved in the stack and will persist as long as `main` doesn't
return. But this is only a very small example. In a complex program where you
have many more variables, objects, etc. it's a bad idea to simply declare all
variables you need in `main`. So it's best that objects get created when they
are needed.

For example you could have a function that creates the object and another one
that calls `create_node` and uses that object.

```
struct node *create_node(int data)
{
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL; // no more memory left

    head->data = data;
    head->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

struct node *foo(void)
{
    struct node *head = create_node(112);

    // do somethig with head

    return head;
}
```

Here `create_node` uses malloc to allocate memory for one `struct node`
object, initializes the object with some values and returns a pointer to that memory location.
`foo` calls `create_node` and does something with it and it returns the
object. If another function calls `foo`, this function will get the object.

There are also other reasons for `malloc`. Consider this code:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int numbers[4] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };

    ...
}
```

In this case you know that you will need 4 integers. But sometimes you need an
array where the number of elements is only known during runtime, for example
because it depends on some user input. For this you can also use `malloc`.

```
void foo(int size)
{
    int *numbers = malloc(size * sizeof *numbers);

    // now you have "size" elements
    ...
    free(numbers);   // freeing memory
}
```

When you use `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, you'll need to free the memory. If
your program does not need the memory anymore, you have to use `free` (like in
the last example. Note that for simplicity I omitted the use of `free` in the
examples with `struct head`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have invokes undefined behavior because you don't really have a node,, you have a *pointer* to a node that doesn't actually point to a node.  Using `malloc` and friends creates a memory region where an actual node object can reside, and where a node pointer can point to.

In your code, `struct node* head` is a pointer that points to nowhere, and dereferencing it as you have done is undefined behavior (which can commonly cause a segfault).  You must point `head` to a valid `struct node` before you can safely dereference it.  One way is like this:

```
int main() {
    struct node* head;
    struct node myNode;
    head = &myNode;  // assigning the address of myNode to head, now head points somewhere
    head->data = 2;  // this is legal
    printf("%d \n", head->data);  // will print 2

}
```

But in the above example, `myNode` is a local variable, and will go out of scope as soon as the function exists (in this case `main`).  As you say in your question, for linked lists you generally want to `malloc` the data so it can be used outside of the current scope.

```
int main() {
    struct node* head = malloc(sizeof struct node);
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        // we received a valid memory block, so we can safely dereference
        // you should ALWAYS initialize/assign memory when you allocate it.
        // malloc does not do this, but calloc does (initializes it to 0) if you want to use that
        // you can use malloc and memset together.. in this case there's just
        // two fields, so we can initialize via assignment.
        head->data = 2;
        head->next = NULL;
        printf("%d \n", head->data);

        // clean up memory when we're done using it
        free(head);
    }
    else
    {
        // we were unable to obtain memory
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a very simple example.  Normally for a linked list, you'll have insert function(s) (where the `malloc`ing generally takes place and remove function(s) (where the `free`ing generally takes place.  You'll at least have a `head` pointer that always points to the first item in the list, and for a double-linked list you'll want a `tail` pointer as well.  There can also be print functions, `deleteEntireList` functions, etc.  But one way or another, you must allocate space for an actual object.  `malloc` is a way to do that so the validity of the memory persists throughout runtime of your program.

---

edit:

Incorrect. This absolutely applies to `int` and `int*`,, it applies to any object and pointer(s) to it.  If you were to have the following:

```
int main() {
    int* head;
    *head = 2;  // head uninitialized and unassigned, this is UB
    printf("%d\n", *head); // UB again

    return 0;
}
```

this is every bit of undefined behavior as you have in your OP.  A pointer **must** point to something valid before you can dereference it.  In the above code, `head` is uninitialized, it doesn't point to anything deterministically, and as soon as you do `*head` (whether to read or write), you're invoking undefined behavior.  Just as with your `struct node`, you must do something like following to be correct:

```
int main() {
        int myInt;  // creates space for an actual int in automatic storage (most likely the stack)
        int* head = &myInt;  // now head points to a valid memory location, namely myInt
        *head = 2;  // now myInt == 2
        printf("%d\n", *head);  // prints 2

        return 0;
    }
```

or you can do

```
int main() {
        int* head = malloc(sizeof int);  // silly to malloc a single int, but this is for illustration purposes
        if (head != NULL)
        {
            // space for an int was returned to us from the heap
            *head = 2; // now the unnamed int that head points to is 2
            printf("%d\n", *head);  // prints out 2
            // don't forget to clean up
            free(head);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error, print error message, etc
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

These rules are true for any primitive type or data structure you're dealing with.  Pointers must point to something, otherwise dereferencing them is undefined behavior, and you *hope* you get a segfault when that happens so you can track down the errors before your TA grades it or before the customer demo.  Murphy's law dictates UB will always crash your code when it's being presented.

Comment: ok thanks very much for the answer, but i still don't get why we don't need to follow the same process when it comes to simple variables like int. For istance when i declare a pointer to an integer value, why don't i need to declare an integer and then assign to the pointer its adress before actually being able to modify the variable's value through the pointer preceded by the * operator?

Comment: @AntonioPavan I think you've got it now, but see my edit for further explanation if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Statement `struct node* head;` defines a *pointer* to a node object, but not the node object itself. As you do not initialize the pointer (i.e. by letting it point to a node object created by, for example, a `malloc`-statement), dereferencing this pointer as you do with `head->data` yields undefined behaviour.

Two ways to overcome this, (1) either allocate memory dynamically - yielding an object with dynamic storage duration, or (2) define the object itself as an, for example, local variable with automatic storage duration:

**(1) dynamic storage duration**

```
int main() {
    struct node* head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    if (head) {
      head->data = 2;
      printf("%d \n", head->data);
      free(head);
    }
}
```

**(2) automatic storage duration**

```
int main() {
    struct node head;
    head.data = 2;
    printf("%d \n", head.data);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks very much for the answer, but i still don't get why we don't need to follow the same process when it comes to simple variables like int. For istance when i declare a pointer to an integer value, why don't i need to declare an integer and then assign to the pointer its adress before actually being able to modify the variable's value through the pointer preceded by the * operator?

Comment: No difference actually; `int *iptr; *iptr=10;` yields undefined  behaviour, too.

Comment: Thanks again, i somehow thought the contrary.